# Zend Form Delete button

Tags: button, zend-framework, zend-form, factory

Well this might sound easy but to me it is confusing as heck. I have been working on a form to edit an already existing database entry. Some of the fields are created and populated based on records from a joined table.

This sounds a bit sketchy so I'll try to illustrate it. I have a table with content named Content and a table named Files which holds the filenames and locations. I get the filenames based on the content id supplied and then the form creates the fields and these are then populated with the filenames.

```
public function setFiles($files) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $i++;
        $fieldname = "encloseditemname{$i}";
        $this->addElement('text', $fieldname, array('required'       => true,
                                                        'label'          => 'Enclosed item name (test)',
                                                        'value'          => $file['file_url'],
        ));
    }
}
```

This works perfectly fine but now I want to add a button that will allow me to delete ONE of the files. So what I figured is should do is create a `fileDeleteAction()` in the controller and then have the button redirect to that action, have it delete the entry in the database and then render the view with the form.

Having the action render a different view then it's standard view, not a problem. Writing the code to delete the entry in the database, not a problem either. Creating a button which redirects to the delete action using the addElements method as a factory... massive problem. This is how far I got.

```
$this->addElement('button', "deleteencloseditem{$i}", array( ??? ));
```

How do I get this button to redirect to the delete action without it disturbing the submit button at the bottom of my form which is used to submit the form and call to the editAction in my controller.

I have looked into using a bit of javascript to detect which button is pressed but I am not at home in javascript yet and am having trouble finding out how to find out which button is pressed since the button name and id are dependant on the setFiles function and thus can range between `deleteencloseditem1` and `deleteencloseditem5000` depending on the amount of filenames it pushes into the form.

How can I get this done? Any tips or advice is well appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An HTML `<form>` can only have one `action` attribute to which the form is routed when submitted. However, there are workarounds to overcome this, both client side and server side.

**Server side**

1. Let all the buttons simply submit to your form's `action` (set by `$this->setAction(...)` in your form's code)
2. In this action, determine which button was clicked by checking the `post` (or `get`) variables
3. Redirect to the correct action based on the button that was clicked

**Client side**

Use the button's `click` event to determine which button was clicked. I assume the button's `ID` tells you something about the file you're deleting. Assuming you give all the delete buttons a `class="delete"`, you could do the following using jQuery:

```
$('input.delete').click(function(){
    // remove 'deleteencloseditem' from the button's ID
    // to only keep the file number
    var myFileID = $(this).attr('id').replace('deleteencloseditem', '');
    window.location.href = 'myLocation?fileID=' + myFileID;
});
```

Comment: Your client side version is sadly not working. It seems to be unable to find wich button is pressed. `$('input.delete').click(function(){
` is picking up buttons with the type set to delete, without my own extended version of the submit button i can't set the button attribute type. It will either be 'button' as i create a button element in my top post, or a submit if i would decide to create a submit button element.

Currently trying the server side solution.

Comment: I have gotten the server side version working, as you suggested i had the action figure out wich button was pressed and based on the had it forward to the correct action, wich then deletes entry and then redirects to the previous action page. 

And I will admit that at first i forwarded again after deleting the entry only to end up in an infinite loop only interrupted by trying to delete the same record a second time giving a DB error. Luckely that's fixed with using redirect instead.

Comment: Glad you've got the server side version working. As for the client side approach: you can of course change `$('input.delete')` into whatever identifies your delete buttons. If your delete buttons are all `<button>`'s and you don't have other `<button>` tags on your page, you could of course use `$('button')`. Or, to be sure, `$('button[name^="deleteencloseditem"]')`, which selects buttons with a name attribute starting with `deleteencloseditem`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the routing. Routing for forms means to direct the `action` to the corresponding route. Your path in the form's action will cause the routing in ZF to use the associated controller and action.

Comment: I have looked into this solution, sadly however it results into another problem for me. While it does indeed work as intended it does create one problem. It works for ALL submit buttons on the form including the one i actually just want to submit the form with.

So it would work if i could find out how to check wich of these buttons is pressed and then decide wich route to follow.

Looking at my question i realise i haven't mentioned this button so i'll edit it :)

Comment: @Björn Quite frankly I don't prefer this solution anyway but in terms of implementing controllers and actions that's the only solution. I prefer one single controller/action and evaluate the params submitted with the POST. Depending on the form I will either directly call models or use `_forward()`. Note that actions are also linked to views.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to fix this would be to just use a link for the delete action and then style it as a button.

Alternatively you can use two buttons with one form you just have to label them differently and test for the label name on POST.

```
if ($this->getRequest()->getPost('submit') == 'Label')
```

Comment: This doesn't work, `$this->getRequest()->getPost()` will return an array containing the post variables and there is no variable called `'submit'`. So it's not entirely a surprise that `$this->getRequest()->getPost('submit')` returns nothing and thus cannot be compared to `'label'`

Comment: you have something being passed that you can test against. Typically it would be an input element of type=submit, usually name=submit with a value=submit or delete or Label or...  this element will pass through the request object as name=>value.